# Importepub plugin lucimoo moodle

Tags: php, import, moodle, epub

I'm working with an old version of moodle(2.0.6) and I can't change this version.

The problem is, when I install the [importepub plugin](http://lucidor.org/get.php?id=moodle-booktool_importepub-0.16.zip) and create a course it doesn´t show me the option import chapter from epub.

I work with this versions:

Moodle: 2.0.6

importepub: 0.16

Comment: There's some notes in the readme.txt about installing manually. Did you follow those?

Answer (score 0):

You import ebooks into a Moodle Book activity/resource.

Lucimoo ebook import and export are now available from the Moodle plugin directory, see https://moodle.org/plugins/view/booktool_importepub and https://moodle.org/plugins/view/booktool_exportepub for screenshots.

You need the Moodle Book module installed and activated. Since you already know you have an older Moodle version than 2.3, I will assume you have followed Lucimoo manual , which says:
"Requirements

The book module is included in Moodle 2.3 and later, and by default these add-ons can only be installed in these versions of Moodle. If you use Moodle 2.0-2.2 and have manually installed the book module and want to use these add-ons, you must remove the line "$plugin->requires = 2012062500;" from the files "importepub/version.php" and "exportepub/version.php" before they can be installed."

In your Moodle course, you then need to add a Moodle Book activity/resource first, as Lucimoo imports content into or exports content from this Moodle Book.

After adding the Moodle Book to your course, you should now see "Import chapters from ebook" and "Import ebook as new book".

"Import chapters from ebook" will import the content of your chosen EPUB ebook file into the current Moodle Book.

"Import ebook as new book" will create a new Moodle Book with the content of your chosen EPUB ebook file. This will then be adjacent to the current Moodle Book you are in at the moment. This is a peculiarity of the current Moodle Book module.